# Regex that matches a pattern and doesn't match specific words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have my basic javascript regex for any string containing at least one alphabet:

```
^(.*[A-Za-z]+.*)+
```

Now I want to update this regex so it won't match the following words: "n\a" and "none". Containing them is valid, meaning "n\aa" or "nn\a" are valid, and just words that are an exact match to the words I don't want will cause regex not to match.

I saw that many examples to words not containing specific string using negative lookbehind like

```
^(?!.*bar).*$
```

but I wasn't able to transform it to work with exact match.

Comment: Try `^(\bn/a\b|\bnone\b)`

Comment: Try `/^(?![\s\S]*\b(?:n\\a|none)\b)[^a-z]*[a-z][\s\S]*$/i`

Comment: do you want to match the words or to just test/validate ?

Comment: *containing at least one alphabet* An [alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet) is a set of written symbols used to write a language, such as the Roman alphabet used to write English. You mean "letter" or "alphabetic character". With regard to your regexp, I'm not sure what the `^` and parentheses and `.*` all mean--it is exactly equivalent to writing `/a-z/i`. By the way, what do you mean by `\a`? Do you mean a literal backslash followed by an "a"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?!)` is actually a negative lookahead. But you are correct that it holds the key here:

```
^(?!n\\a$)(?!none$)(.*[A-Za-z].*)
```

Basically, starting at the beginning (`^`) we want to ensure that til the end (`$`) the string does not consist solely of these two.

To make this case insensitive, you can just add the `i` regex flag:

```
'NONE'.match(/^(?!n\\a$)(?!none$)(.*[A-Za-z].*)/)  // => ["NONE", "NONE"]
'NONE'.match(/^(?!n\\a$)(?!none$)(.*[A-Za-z].*)/i) // => null
```

---

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/o4xuMH/3)

Also note that your original regex didn't need the `+`s as matching one already ensures the presence of at least one.

Comment: Actually, all `+` are redundant in the original pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the correction in the original and for the perfect and fast anser

Comment: @RotemB, happy to help.

Comment: @ndn, how can I make this regex case-insensitive?

Comment: @RotemB, when constructing the regex, add the `i` flag. Aka `/regex-here/i`.

Comment: @ndn, any change you can update your example? I'm trying uselessly to make the words case-insensitive and getting either compilation errors or string with i as the compared values. Thanks again